# Hadoop cluster is in safe mode ( Namenode is in safe mode) What resources do I need to free in order to remove the safe mode?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, bigdata

I have taken the snapshot of my cluster. Here are my findings:

```
Safe mode is ON
Configured Capacity: 47430737653760 (43.14 TB)
Present Capacity: 20590420062208 (18.73 TB)
DFS Remaining: 19343468953600 (17.59 TB)
DFS Used: 1246951108608 (1.13 TB)
DFS Used%: 6.06%
Under replicated blocks: 2
Blocks with corrupt replicas: 0
Missing blocks: 0

-------------------------------------------------
Live datanodes (5):

Name: 10.0.70.144:50010 (slave2)
Hostname: slave2
Decommission Status : Normal
Configured Capacity: 9486147530752 (8.63 TB)
DFS Used: 209829912576 (195.42 GB)
Non DFS Used: 4733044670464 (4.30 TB)
DFS Remaining: 4543272947712 (4.13 TB)
DFS Used%: 2.21%
DFS Remaining%: 47.89%
Configured Cache Capacity: 0 (0 B)
Cache Used: 0 (0 B)
Cache Remaining: 0 (0 B)
Cache Used%: 100.00%
Cache Remaining%: 0.00%
Xceivers: 1
Last contact: Sat Oct 13 16:57:21 IST 2018


Name: 10.0.70.143:50010 (slave1)
Hostname: slave1
Decommission Status : Normal
Configured Capacity: 9486147530752 (8.63 TB)
DFS Used: 206771748864 (192.57 GB)
Non DFS Used: 4070449033216 (3.70 TB)
DFS Remaining: 5208926748672 (4.74 TB)
DFS Used%: 2.18%
DFS Remaining%: 54.91%
Configured Cache Capacity: 0 (0 B)
Cache Used: 0 (0 B)
Cache Remaining: 0 (0 B)
Cache Used%: 100.00%
Cache Remaining%: 0.00%
Xceivers: 1
Last contact: Sat Oct 13 16:57:21 IST 2018


Name: 10.0.70.145:50010 (slave3)
Hostname: slave3
Decommission Status : Normal
Configured Capacity: 9486147530752 (8.63 TB)
DFS Used: 205542408192 (191.43 GB)
Non DFS Used: 5523446423552 (5.02 TB)
DFS Remaining: 3757158699008 (3.42 TB)
DFS Used%: 2.17%
DFS Remaining%: 39.61%
Configured Cache Capacity: 0 (0 B)
Cache Used: 0 (0 B)
Cache Remaining: 0 (0 B)
Cache Used%: 100.00%
Cache Remaining%: 0.00%
Xceivers: 1
Last contact: Sat Oct 13 16:57:21 IST 2018


Name: 10.0.70.147:50010 (slave5)
Hostname: slave5
Decommission Status : Normal
Configured Capacity: 9486147530752 (8.63 TB)
DFS Used: 209182961664 (194.82 GB)
Non DFS Used: 5516635717632 (5.02 TB)
DFS Remaining: 3760328851456 (3.42 TB)
DFS Used%: 2.21%
DFS Remaining%: 39.64%
Configured Cache Capacity: 0 (0 B)
Cache Used: 0 (0 B)
Cache Remaining: 0 (0 B)
Cache Used%: 100.00%
Cache Remaining%: 0.00%
Xceivers: 1
Last contact: Sat Oct 13 16:57:22 IST 2018


Name: 10.0.70.146:50010 (slave4)
Hostname: slave4
Decommission Status : Normal
Configured Capacity: 9486147530752 (8.63 TB)
DFS Used: 415624077312 (387.08 GB)
Non DFS Used: 6996741746688 (6.36 TB)
DFS Remaining: 2073781706752 (1.89 TB)
DFS Used%: 4.38%
DFS Remaining%: 21.86%
Configured Cache Capacity: 0 (0 B)
Cache Used: 0 (0 B)
Cache Remaining: 0 (0 B)
Cache Used%: 100.00%
Cache Remaining%: 0.00%
Xceivers: 1
Last contact: Sat Oct 13 16:57:21 IST 2018
```

What resources do I need to free to make the NN leave the safemode. I can try the dfsadmin safemode leave command but I need to make sure that the running of MR jobs do not fail the next time. I am trying to process 400GB of text data through the MR job. I have another 3.2 TB of data left to process. Please assist me in processing the data efficiently.

Comment: MR jobs typically don't process data effeciently anyway. What jobs are you trying to do? What errors are you getting when they fail? Because storage clearly isn't the reason and YARN jobs typically don't cause a namenode to enter safe mode... Go to look at its logs

Comment: Here is what the logs say when I do a simple ls of raw_data directory in hdfs. The raw_data directory has 1.8 million files : `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded`

Comment: Yeah, Hadoop is not suited for millions of small files. You should either compress and archive them all, or you must increase the namenode heap size

Comment: However, I don't think that this is the issue. The main issue is     `[hduser@secondary mapper]$ df -h
    Filesystem               Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
    /dev/mapper/centos-root  1.1T 1011G   19M 100% /` The centos-root dir is 100% full. I need to remove some files which are consuming most of the space.

Answer (score 1):

The Namenode had disk space issues. `/dev/mapper/centos-root` was 100% full.
I removed some files from it to create some space. Here is the current snapshot:

```
[hduser@secondary ~]$ df 
Filesystem               1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/centos-root 1116838084 557248752 502833928  53% /
```

After creating space, I exited the safemode using command `hadoop dfsadmin -safemode leave` and ran my MR job which completed successfully.